# how can i return array values from function?

Tags: php, arrays

i have some problem with this function ( search value inside subarray):

```
function searchItemsByKey($arr, $looking_key) {
    $all_values= array ();
    echo "cycling... <br>";
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value)
    {
        if (is_array($arr[$key]))
         searchItemsByKey($arr[$key], $looking_key);
        else   if ($key == $looking_key)
        {
            echo "find value " . $key . " => " . $value  . "<br>";
        array_push ($all_values,$value);
        }
    }
    return $all_values;
}

$myvalues =  searchItemsByKey($array, 'end');
print_r ($myvalues);
```

myvalues, is array null.
how can i do ?

Comment: Since you didn't include any inputs I made my own and as far as I can see it return works, maybe your function doesn't. https://3v4l.org/jaHHO

Comment: la mia funzione non funziona, puoi provare con una semplice aray. you know why dosen't work ? thanks .

Answer (score 0):

replace with this

else   if ($value == $looking_key)

Comment: i want that that key is like looking_key, not value

Answer (score 0):

Your biggest problem is that when you search the sub-arrays, you do the sub-search but ignore the results. So at most, you'll only ever find stuff one level deep.

The solution to that problem is, when you are looking in a sub-array, to tack on the return value from the sub-search to `$all_values`.

```
function searchItemsByKey($arr, $looking_key)
{
    $all_values= array();
    echo "cycling... <br>";
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value)
    {
        // btw...not much point in `$arr[$key]` here.
        // the `$key => $value` means that the value will be put in $value.
        if (is_array($value))
        {
            array_splice($all_values, count($all_values), 0, array_searchItemsByKey($value, $looking_key);
        }
        else if ($key == $looking_key)
        {
            echo "find value " . $key . " => " . $value  . "<br>";
            array_push ($all_values,$value);
        }
    }
    return $all_values;
}

$myvalues =  searchItemsByKey($array, 'end');
print_r ($myvalues);
```

Comment: thanks a lot! now work :),   $all_result is it array ? can i declare like all_values? because i have this Notice: Undefined variable: all_results

Comment: @FranciscoSour: Oops. That should have been `$all_values`. :P  Edited.